# Durbin Watson Test for an AR(1) process

Tags: econometrics, time-series, autoregressive

$(1)  y_t =\beta y_{t-1} +\epsilon_t$

$(2)  \epsilon_t =\rho \epsilon_{t-1} +v_t$

Where $v_t$ is i.i.d white noise. I know that OLS estimates of (1) are biased. It would then follow that estimates of $\epsilon_t$ are biased, which should imply a Durbin-Watson Test using those residual estimates is biased. I have been attempting to prove this, but have struggled, and likely I am making algebra mistakes. Is there a straightforward proof that the Durbin-Watson test is biased?

I have that $plim \hat{\beta}_{OLS}=\beta +\frac{\rho (1-\beta^2)}{1+\beta\rho}$ which implies $\hat{\epsilon_t}=\epsilon_t-y_{t-1}\frac{\rho (1-\beta^2)}{1+\beta\rho}$
and $Cov[y_{t-1},\epsilon_t]=\frac{\rho \sigma^2_\epsilon}{(1-\beta \rho)}$.

Comment: See https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909547 (Testing for Serial Correlation in Least-Squares Regression When Some of the Regressors are Lagged Dependent Variables, Econometrica, Vol 38, No 3, 1970, 410-421).

Comment: The above paper is written by Durbin himself. Also this one: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909870 (Nerlove and Wallis, Use of the Durbin-Watson Statistic in Inappropriate Situations, Econometrica, Vol 34, No 1, 1966, 235-238). Their equations (1) and (2) are identical to your (1) and (2).

Comment: @chan1142 please consider expanding it into an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nerlove and Wallis (1966) result**

[Nerlove and Wallis (1966)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909870) have discussed this issue. Their Equation (3) derives the probability limit of the Durbin-Watson statistic as:
$$\mathrm{plim}\, d^* = 2 \left[ 1 - \frac{\rho \beta (\beta + \rho)}{1+\beta \rho} \right].$$
(Their notation for $\beta$ is $\alpha$ in the paper.) Nerlove and Wallis's (1966) derivation is based on [Malinvaud (1961)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1401655), whose beautiful work I can't read, unfortunately.

**Derivation**

Nerlove and Wallis's (1966) result can be derived. Let me try it here. We need $y_t$ to be covariance stationary, which we just assume.

Let $\gamma_j = E(y_t y_{t-j})$. Let $b$ be the probability limit of $\hat\beta_{ols}$, which is $b=(\beta+\rho)/(1+\beta\rho)$ according to OP's derivation. Let $e_t = y_t - b y_{t-1}$. Then
\begin{align}
E(e_t^2) &= (1+b^2) \gamma_0 - 2b \gamma_1\\
E(e_t e_{t-1}) &= \gamma_1 -b\gamma_2 - b\gamma_0 + b^2 \gamma_1 = (1+b^2) \gamma_1 - b(\gamma_0+\gamma_2),
\end{align}
and the probability limit of DW ($d^*$) is $2[1-E(e_te_{t-1})/E(e_t^2)]$.

We need $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. For this, note that $\epsilon_t - \rho \epsilon_{t-1} = (y_t - \beta y_{t-1}) - \rho(y_{t-1} - \beta y_{t-2}) = v_t$, that is, $y_t = (\beta + \rho) y_{t-1} - \beta \rho y_{t-2} + v_t$. Due to covariance stationarity, we have (because $E y_{t-1} v_t = 0$ and $E y_{t-2} v_t = 0$)
\begin{align*}
\gamma_1 &= (\beta + \rho) \gamma_0 - \beta\rho \gamma_1,\\
\gamma_2 &= (\beta + \rho) \gamma_1 - \beta\rho \gamma_0,
\end{align*}
the [Yule-Walker equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule%E2%80%93Walker_equations).
The first identity implies $\gamma_1/\gamma_0 = (\beta+\rho)/(1+\beta\rho) = b$, which is natural because $\hat\beta_{ols}$ converges in probability to $\gamma_1/\gamma_0$. The second identity implies $\gamma_2/\gamma_0 = (\beta+\rho) (\gamma_1/\gamma_0) - \beta\rho = (\beta+\rho) b - \beta\rho$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{E(e_te_{t-1})}{E(e_t^2)} &= \frac{(1+b^2) \gamma_1 - b(\gamma_0+\gamma_2)}{(1+b^2)\gamma_0 - 2b\gamma_1}
= \frac{(1+b^2)b - b[1+(\beta+\rho)b -\beta\rho]}{1+b^2 - 2b^2}\\
&= \frac{b^3-(\beta+\rho)b^2+\beta\rho b}{1-b^2} = b \left[ \frac{b^2 - (\beta + \rho) b + \beta\rho}{1-b^2} \right].
\end{align}
Plug in $b = (\beta+\rho)/(1+\beta\rho)$ to show that the above equals
$$
b \left[ \frac{(\beta+\rho)^2 - (\beta+\rho)^2 (1+\beta\rho) + \beta\rho (1+\beta\rho)^2}{(1+\beta\rho)^2 - (\beta+\rho)^2} \right] = b\beta\rho = \frac{\beta\rho(\beta+\rho)}{1+\beta\rho},
$$
which straightforwardly implies Nerlove and Wallis's (1966) result because $d^* \to_p 2[1- E(e_te_{t-1})/E(e_t^2)]$.

**The Durbin h statistic**

[Durbin (1970)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909547) acknowledges this problem and proposes the so-called *Durbin-h statistic*, whose formula is given in his Equation (12) on p. 419 as:
$$h = a\sqrt{\frac{n}{1-n\hat{V}(b_1)}}, \quad a = 1-\tfrac12 d,$$
asymptotically standard normal under the null. (See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic).) You can guess the reason it is called the Durbin "h" statistic.

**Meaning of DW biased**

Nerlove and Wallis (1966) further explain why their derivation of the probability limit of DW $d^*$ leads to invalid testing by DW. Yet, under the null hypothesis that $\rho=0$, DW $d^*$ converges in probability to 2 (which is "correct"), so we cannot simply jump to the conclusion that the DW test consistently rejects the correct null. The problem, I would say, is in the standard error of $d^*$ (or of the estimated serial correlation in $y_t - \hat\beta_{ols} y_{t-1}$). And Durbin (1970) gives a solution.

**References**

Durbin, J. (1970). [Testing for Serial Correlation in Least-Squares Regression When Some of the Regressors are Lagged Dependent Variables](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909547), *Econometrica* 38(3), 410-421.

Malinvaud, E. (1961). [Estimation et Prevision dans les Modeles Economiques Autoregressifs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1401655), *Review of the International Institute of Statistics*, 29(2), 1-32.

Nerlove, M., and K. F. Wallis (1966). [Use of the Durbin-Watson Statistic in Inappropriate Situations](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909870), *Econometrica* 34(1), 235-238.

Comment: Incredible answer, just one minor typo. After "For this, note that", you wrote $e_t -e_{t-1}$ where I think you meant $e_t-\rho e_{t-1}$

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it.

Comment: Also added discussions on the "bias" of DW.